# NullReferenceException dynamically created controls, object seems to exist

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, null, controls

In Win Forms I have these three test methods. First to create a button, second to create a tab control with two tabs and third to move created button to first tab.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button przycisk = new Button();
        przycisk.Location = new Point(24, 250);
        przycisk.Name = "nowy";
        przycisk.Text = "utworzony";
        przycisk.Width = 131;
        przycisk.Height = 23;
        Controls.Add(przycisk);
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TabControl zakladki = new TabControl();
        zakladki.Location = new Point(208, 160);
        zakladki.Name = "zakl";
        zakladki.Height = 150;
        zakladki.Width = 208;
        zakladki.TabPages.Add("zakladka1", "pierwsza");
        zakladki.TabPages.Add("zakladka2", "druga");
        Controls.Add(zakladki);
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TabControl zakladki = (TabControl)Controls.Find("zakl", false).FirstOrDefault();
        int numerZakladki = 1;
        foreach (TabPage zakladka in zakladki.TabPages)
        {
            Control kt = Controls["nowy"];
            kt.Location = new Point(10, 10); // System.NullReferenceException
            zakladka.Controls.Add(kt);
            numerZakladki++;
        }
    }
```

I'm having a hard time to understand the behavior upon trying to change the referenced button location. The code above throws System.NullReferenceException, but when I do

```
if (kt != null)
{
    kt.Location = new Point(10, 10);
}
```

it works as expected. Can anyone explain it to me ?

Comment: Have you clicked `button1` (i.e. created `przycisk` control)?

Comment: Yes I have clicked buttons in correct order :)

Comment: Notice, you are adding `button1` to the `form`, **not** `zakl` (**I know this is old, but still..**)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new TabControl contains two Tabs. 
If you move the button to the first Tab, the control at the Main form is null.
Code without Loop:

```
    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TabControl zakladki = (TabControl)Controls.Find("zakl", false).FirstOrDefault();
        Control kt = Controls["nowy"];
        kt.Location = new Point(10, 10);
        zakladki.TabPages[0].Controls.Add(kt);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `nowy` controls are added to the root control (`Form` I guess), but you are trying to find them in the tab pages under `zakl`. You have to either add the controls to the tab page, or find them in the root control, just like you did with `zakl`.

Answer (score 0):

You move the "nowy" button from the `Form.Controls` to the first `TabPage`'s `Controls` collection. This removes the control from the first collection, so the code throws the exception on the next iteration. A `Control` can have only a single`Parent`.

Either create the `Button` for each tab separately (instead of moving it), or add the `Button` to the first tab only (without the `foreach` loop).